# Model agency database opinion

Tags: database, codeigniter, database-design

I would like to make a model agency based on codeigniter, but im a but stuck with the database, exactly the registration part.

I would like to allow users to sign up as, model, photohgrapher, agency, or make-up artist.

So could someoone give me an opinion how to make the database? Like seperate the models, photographers, agencies, and artists in diferent tables, and at the registration form only ask for baseic info? like name, password, email, D.O.B., or there is a nother way?.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use entity sub-typing with a parent type of "USER", which will contain your basic information, and with sub-types of "MODEL", "AGENCY", "PHOTOGRAPHER", "MAKEUP_ARTIST".  This will allow you to have a better user experience for the inevitable case where there is overlap.  I'm sure there are photographers who have agencies and agencies that do make-up etc.  It would be much better for these types of users to have a single user ID and password despite having different types of profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Make a drop down for different type of people signing up which the data for drop down comes from a separate table (e.g. `person_type`) from database and save the basic details of the person in separate table with the ID of the `person_type` table.

You can make a model for getting, inserting and updating records for this purpose.